# Registration Manager sometimes null but SDK correct initialized

Tags: mobilesdk, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, registration

sometimes i receive a null pointer exception inside my app when i want to send some data with the registration manager to the SFMC.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.RegistrationManager$Editor com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.RegistrationManager.edit()' on a null object reference
```

this is the line where the crash happens:

```
    if (salesforceSdk.isReady()) {
    salesforceSdk.requestSdk(MarketingCloudSdk.WhenReadyListener { sdk ->
            sdk.registrationManager.edit().setAttribute("bla", "bla").commit()
        }
    }
```

the method where the crash happens will be just invoked when the Status of the Initialization is usable:

```
        if (!salesforceSdk.isInitializing() && !salesforceSdk.isReady()) {
            try {
                salesforceSdk.init(context, MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
                    .setApplicationId(applicationId)
                    .setAccessToken(accessToken)
                    .setMid(mid)
                    .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(marketingCloudUrl)
                    .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
                    .setInboxEnabled(true)
                    .build(context), MarketingCloudSdk.InitializationListener { status ->
                    if (status.isUsable) {
                        syncSalesforcePreferences()
                        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.i("blabla",
                                                      MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance()?.registrationManager?.someAttributes()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

is this a known bug or am i doing something wrong? To be clear: this doesen't happen regularly but sometimes and this behaviour inside our production app is not an option. 
I am using the Version 6.3.3 of the Salesforce SDK.

Thx for your help!

edit referring to the question:

those methods (isReady, isInitializing, init, requestSDK) are wrapped by an interface. This is the implementation:

```
        override fun isInitializing(): Boolean = MarketingCloudSdk.isInitializing()

    override fun isReady() = MarketingCloudSdk.isReady()

    override fun requestSdk(mark: WhenReadyListener) = MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(mark)

    override fun init(context: Context, marketingCloudConfig: MarketingCloudConfig,
                      initializationListener: InitializationListener) = MarketingCloudSdk.init(context, marketingCloudConfig,
                                                                                               initializationListener)
```

Comment: Where is the `sdk` variable set?  Are you calling `getInstance` immediately before editing the registration, or are you setting the variable, then sometime later modifying the registration.  Sharing more of your code would help find a potential issue in SDK usage.  If you don't want that code here you can open a ticket with your Salesforce support representative.

Comment: I've edited my questions and posted some more code. 

The call of getInstance() just happens for logging purposes. Is this a mistake? Or may i ensure to do that later after setting the values to the registrationmanager?

The sdk variable is set by the WhenReadyListener of the SDK.

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping the SDK methods?  Can you remove the wrapper and instead call the MarketingCloudSdk class directly.  It will handle managing the instance of the SDK so I see no need to wrap its methods with another class.  Removing this will eliminate the possibility that it has introduced the issue.

Comment: The purpose of wrapping the SDK Methods is for the Unit- / UI-Tests. With the Interface its easier to mock those methods.

Comment: MarketingCloudSdk.getInstance()?.registrationManager?.deviceId is sometimes null aswell after a successful registration. There is no wrapping and tbh i dont think the wrapping has any effect. Does the sdk has some retry functionality when editing any preferences failed?

Comment: You should reach out to a Salesforce support representative for further assistance.

Comment: hi Lars, I'm having the same issue with version 7 of the SFMC SDK, did you solve it?

Comment: hi, its been a while so i am not 100 % sure but i think it was some kind of a race condition. The SDK initialized twice. So it was in a ready state because the first initialization worked. But because the second initialization was started some keys got nulled. Could you ensure this is not happening?